# Adding elements to an array via array_push

Tags: php, arrays, yii

Am trying to push elements to an `array` but they fail

This is what i have tried:

```
  $relations=['0'=>''];
    $hhrelations = Tblsuhhrelationship::model()->findAll();
    foreach ($hhrelations as $key=>$hhrelation){

       array_push($relations, $hhrelation['description'],(int)$hhrelation['hh_relation_id']);

     }
   var_dump($relations)
```

This generates an array in this form:

```
  1 => string 'Head' (length=4)
   2 => int 1
  3 => string 'Spouse' (length=6)
  4 => int 2
  5 => string 'Child (own/Step)' (length=16)
  6 => int 3
  7 => string 'Parent/Parent in-law' (length=20)
  8 => int 4
  9 => string 'Brother/Sister' (length=14)
 10 => int 5
  11 => string 'Other Relatives' (length=15)
  12 => int 6
  13 => string 'Unrelated' (length=9)
  14 => int 7
```

I would like it to be:

```
  1 => string 'Head' (length=4)
  2 => string 'Spouse' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Child (own/Step)' (length=16)
  4 => string 'Parent/Parent in-law' (length=20)
  5 => string 'Brother/Sister' (length=14)
//Others continue this way
```

Where the values `1,2,3..` are given by `$hhrelation['hh_relation_id']`

And the strings are given by `$hhrelation['description']`

How do i modify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason to use array_push instead of a simple assignment?

```
$relations[(int)$hhrelation['hh_relation_id'])] = $hhrelation['description'];
```

The array_push is literally creating one entry per item in the list, hence what you're seeing in the dump.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach ($hhrelations as $key=>$hhrelation){

   $relations[(int)$hhrelation['hh_relation_id']]  = $hhrelation['description'];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, if you are using Yii2 you can use ArrayHelper to create the mapping for you.

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$relations = ArrayHelper::map($hhrelations, 'hh_relation_id', 'description');
```

Comment: Thanks but am using yii1, but ill use it on yii2